# Bootstrap Carousel items not reached by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel, and multiple items inside it. the items inside have scrolling text when its too long, the scrolling logic is handled by jquery and the issue is that only the item that is shown on page load has scrolling text and the others items that come later dont have the scroll effect, it seems that bootstrap carousel is preventing the jquery from running the animation.

question is why does't the animation not happen on items loaded afterwards?

Here is a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwMa9NB9a-8) link

and here is the code im working with

```
<div class="active item">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="container-flex">
            <div class="row  vertical-align">
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center nopadding">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="img.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center nopadding fixture-text scrolltext">
                        A LONG TEXT HERE
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    VS
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center nopadding">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="img.png" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center nopadding fixture-text scrolltext">
                        A LONG TEXT HERE
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 fixture-text text-center scrolltext">
                    A long text here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var txt = $('.scrolltext');
if (txt.get(0).scrollWidth > txt.width() || txt.height() > 15) {
    txt.marquee({
        duration: 5000,
        gap: 0,
        delayBeforeStart: 0,
        direction: 'left',
        duplicated: true
    });
}
```